# cant install react-leaflet on my react project

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

Running into an issue here where I cant install react-leaflet onto my project. I did

```
npm i react-leaflet
```

and it didn't work, and I even did

```
npm i leaflet.
```

What do I do here?

Comment: what error has occurred? could you share it?

Comment: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: dev-chat@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-leaflet@3.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-leaflet
npm ERR!   react-leaflet@"*" from the root project

Answer (score 0):

it might be for your `node` version (maybe you need to upgrade it)

you can try to delete your `node_modules` directory and also `package.json` the `npm i` again

- `rm -R node_modules`
- `rm package-lock.json`
- `npm install`

also adding `--legacy-peer-deps` at the end of installing your package might be helpful

- `npm install react-leaflet --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: Ok, right now im using node version 16.13.0 but ill try to upgrade to the newest version I can and do the steps you said

Answer (score 0):

The error "could not resolve dependency error" comes as react-leaflet@3.2.5 does not work on react versions *below* 18. The project which you are working on has an older react version than 18.

To resolve this, first update react and react-dom -

`npm install react@latest react-dom@latest`

Add leaflet and react-leaflet packages -

`npm install leaflet react-leaflet`

Remember to install the `leaflet` package first before `react-leaflet` as the latter is dependent on the former.